# Does Ubuntu 16.04 work in Coffee Lake

Tags: 16.04, intel

I am looking to buy a new laptop with i5-8250 (coffee lake) and installing Ubuntu 16.04.

At the moment 16.04 is using the kernel 4.10-hwe. Is there temporary support for it in the current hwe? I rather not upgrade my kernel if possible.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. Your best bet would be 18.04 when released, or the development branch now.

Comment: I might have to use hwe-edge kernel.

Comment: Did you end up doing this? What kernel did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

This question got my attention as I've designed and built a system based on the Coffee Lake CPU.Testing indicates that while 16.04.1 installs just fine, it fails to reboot after removing the installation media and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> Upon Power cycling the system it booted and rebooted and shut down as expected with kernel v.4.4.0-134-generic. After updating and upgrading to 16.04.5 it still works as expected. I upgraded the kernel with `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` which upgraded the kernel to 4.15.033-generic #36 which immediately broke the graphics (tried and failed to boot in low graphics mode). I also tried `linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge` with identical unfortunate results.

Research indicated that you would need a newer kernel than 4.10 and might have to add `i915.alpha_support=1` to the kernel flags after (or before) `quiet splash` in `/etc/defaults/grub` on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line [which may work.] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1728313) This does not appear to be accurate (at least on the hardware I chose which is listed below) and may be just a problem with Wayland (which was short-lived and didn't exist in 16.04 and was [dropped from 18.04.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/xorg-will-default-display-server-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Reportedly [this is fixed in kernel 4.15](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.15-CFL-No-Alpha) whereby the Coffee Lake Graphics are no longer treated as Alpha. It might also interest you that in reference to [this comment,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982040/does-ubuntu-16-04-work-in-coffee-lake#comment1578816_982040)
[Dell is selling Kaby Lake / Coffee Lake developer systems with Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled.](https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/3036723/dell-xps-13-developer-edition-comes-rocking-ubuntu-linux-1804-lts) Unless of course you (like me) absolutely insist on designing and building your own gear in which case it's far from interesting.

**EDIT:**

I built a Coffee Lake system and can confirm that both 16.04.1 and 18.04.1 work fine, however I cannot recommend the hwe kernels at this time. Note that all testing was done via fresh installation.

For those who are interested these are the components I chose (The drives I had on the shelf)I had also ordered a Patriot SCORCH M.2 2280 128GB PCIe 3.0 x2 with NVMe but it won't arrive until later. It will be interesting to see how it compares to the ~52similar less than stellar0 MB/sec I'm getting off the OCZ drive.

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte H310M-S2P
CPU: Intel Core i3-8100 3.6GHz quad core
RAM: Geil EVO POTENZA 8GB (2x4GB) DDR4
SSD: OCZ-SOLID3
DVDRW: ASUS DRW-24B1ST
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I write this by using an [i3-8300](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/129942/intel-core-i3-8300-processor-8m-cache-3-70-ghz.html) with [Asus ROG STRIX H370-I GAMING](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-H370-I-GAMING/overview/)
 (see the entire [configuration](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/adrhc/saved/QqzBbv)) with Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS - conclusion, it works :).

```
$uname -a
Linux adr-desktop 4.15.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 17:45:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```